uint256, uint8 and bytes32 in the called smart contract function. [calling smart contract function i nweb3.py]
I want to call a function with certain parameters in web3.py but I have no idea how to specify the parameters in the called function. What are the data types uint256, uint8 and bytes. Can you provide an example in my code so that I understand what these data types are and how to build a transaction.
My code:
from web3 import Web3
import json
binance_testnet_rpc_url = "https://mainnet.base.org"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(binance_testnet_rpc_url))

print(f"Is connected: {web3.is_connected()}")  # Is connected: True
address='MY_ADDRESS'
web3.eth.account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
account=web3.eth.account.from_mnemonic('MY MNEMONIC')

private_key=web3.to_hex(account.key)
ERC20_ABI = json.loads('''[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_token","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnableInvalidOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnableUnauthorizedAccount","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ReentrancyGuardReentrantCall","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"string","name":"id","type":"string"}],"name":"Claimed","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"CLAIM_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_SEPARATOR","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DOMAIN_TYPEHASH","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"id","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"}],"name":"buildClaimSeparator","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"id","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint8[]","name":"v","type":"uint8[]"},{"internalType":"bytes32[]","name":"r","type":"bytes32[]"},{"internalType":"bytes32[]","name":"s","type":"bytes32[]"}],"name":"claimReward","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"lockPeriod","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"nonces","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"period","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setLockPeriod","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"_signers","type":"address[]"}],"name":"setSigners","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"startedAt","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IERC20","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]''')

contract_address = 'ADDRESS'
checksum_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(contract_address)
contract = web3.eth.contract(checksum_address, abi=ERC20_ABI)
Chain_id = web3.eth.chain_id

call_function = contract.functions.claimReward().buildTransaction({'from': address,'value': web3.toWei('1','ether'), 'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),'nonce': 1}) 
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(call_function, private_key=private_key)
send_tx = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_tx)


its claimReward fucntion with parameters (address, uint256, string, uint8[],bytes32[],bytes32[])
and I don’t understand how I can get the uint256 data type, the uint8 array and the bytes32 array
